# How can you create GitHub gists that live under an organization account instead of a personal account?

Tags: github, gist

I manage an organization https://github.com/marklogic.  I see we actually have one gist under https://gist.github.com/marklogic/ ; I can't figure out how to get any more gists there though.  Is there a way?

Comment: see [this discussion about organization gist in community/community](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/7923 "Organization gists · Discussion #7923 · community/community")

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I don't think you can currently create gists as an organization account, but in my experience, if your account was a personal account and you created a gist under that account and then upgraded the account to an organization account, the gist stays but no new gists can be created.

Also, seems like [this answer on WebApps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/42847) confirms my experience.

Comment: What's weird is that we do seem to have one gist under ouir org so we managed, at least once, to do this.  See https://gist.github.com/marklogic

Comment: @EricBloch that org account must have been an individual account earlier on. You can always convert an individual account to an org account and the gists will stay there.

Comment: I'm contemplating just using the wiki for code snippets that belong to the organisation, or even to the individual repositories for that organisation.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - No, you can't do it yet.

**Workaround**

1. Create a repo called gists in your organization and commit all gists
   in that repo.
2. Create a team with all developers, allocate the gists
   repo to the team so that everyone has access.

Comment: How to get a gist url from an uploaded file? I would like to use it for cla-assistant and the url needs to have the format https://gist.github.com/...

Comment: Related: https://github.com/cla-assistant/cla-assistant/issues/926